# Got Null Pointer in BDD Cucumber Selenium UI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

Here my cucumber feature

```
@Regression
Feature: Add to Cart Feature

  Background: user successfully login to website saucedemo
    Given [ui] user open web url "https://www.saucedemo.com/"
    And [ui] user input username "standard_user" and password "secret_sauce"
    When [ui] user click login button
    Then [ui] user success login and redirected to homepage

  @AddToCartTestCase-01
  Scenario: user success add one product to cart
    Given [ui] user click button add to cart on products page
    Then [ui] user should see count of product is "1" in cart on products page
```

Here my step definition for user accses the website in LoginSteps.java

```
public class LoginSteps {

    WebDriver driver;

    LoginPages loginPages;

    @Given("[ui] user open web url {string}")
    public void uiUserOpenWebUrl(String url) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        loginPages = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPages.class);
    }

    @And("[ui] user input username {string} and password {string}")
    public void uiUserInputUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
        loginPages.fillFormUsername(username);
        loginPages.fillFormPassword(password);
    }

    @When("[ui] user click login button")
    public void uiUserClickLoginButton() {
        loginPages.clickLoginButton();
    }

    @Then("[ui] user success login and redirected to homepage")
    public void uiUserSuccessLoginAndRedirectedToHomepage() {
        assertThat("wrong homepage", driver.getCurrentUrl(), equalTo("https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html"));
    }

    @Then("[ui] user should see error message {string}")
    public void uiUserShouldSeeErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        assertThat("wrong error message", loginPages.errorMessage(), equalTo(errorMessage));
    }

    @And("[ui] user close the browser")
    public void uiUserCloseTheBrowser() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Here my step definition for user add product to cart in AddToCartSteps.java

```
public class AddToCartSteps {
    AddToCartPages addToCartPages;

    @Given("[ui] user click button add to cart on products page")
    public void uiUserClickButtonAddToCartOnProductsPage() {
        addToCartPages.clickAddToCartButton();
    }

    @Then("[ui] user should see count of product is {string} in cart on products page")
    public void uiUserShouldSeeCountOfProductIsInCartOnProductsPage(String count) {
        assertThat("number of products in the cart does not change", addToCartPages.getCountOfProduct(), equalTo(count));
    }

}
```

If I run my `@AddToCartTestCase-01`, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in step "*Given [ui] user click button add to cart on products page*."

Could someone to help me, so I can run my scenario? Thank you.

Here my [Foldering Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTbWM.png)

Comment: You are getting an NPE because you did not set a value to `addToCartPages`. This will require that you share the Web Driver between your step definition files. To share the webdriver between step definitions look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-picocontainer